# Eth-Brownie not recognised/ showing as installed even after installation

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, solidity, brownie

I am currentyl struggling with installing Eth-Brownie. I am fairly new to Solidity as well as Python so still getting my bearings so apologies if this is a basic question. Basically I am using python 4.10 as well as the latest version of pip. I had some issues installing pipx and crytoolz but after working through those I am not getting an error every time I attempt to check if eth-brownie has installed.

When running pip list eth brownie is listed and shows as version 1.16 but when I try to check it in the CLI I get this error message

[image]

I seem unable to find a solve for this after a large amount of looking. Any help would be appreciated.

Fixes I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling brownie
- Uninstalling and reinstalling pip
- Uninstalling and reinstalling pipx
- using pipx to install brownie
- adding paths to environment variables ( the paths where eth-brownie is stored ( This for me is appdata/local/packages/pythonsoftwarefoundation(some numbers)/ local-cache/local-packages/Python310/site-packages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `brownie --version`? You can find it in the `Script` folder under the python environment folder.

Comment: Yes. I know I can find this I am just using this as a test to see if it is installed correctly but it is returning the error above. I believe it is an environment variable issue but cant seem to solve it

Comment: @Jack1999 Have you tried `brownie --version` instead of `eth-brownie --version`?

Comment: That returns this error message: PS C:\Users\Jmclo\Documents\Demo\Python_Test> brownie --version
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Comment: I have tried both Python3.9 and 3.10 as well as pip and Pipx to install brownie. No luck

Comment: @Jack1999 Can you get the version of brownie?

Comment: I have fixed this issue. Using the command Brownie --version after adding the brownie file to environment variables seemed to work the trick. Thanks for the help